# Setting Wrong Application Name

Tags: java, android, xml

I have my application named Umall but it is replaced by Slash that is my First Activity i am stuck with that small problem don't know how to handle it.. i gave application name directly in application lable
My Manifest.XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.ef.umall"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="15"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
       android:label="Umall"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.SplashActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.ProductsListActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_products_list" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.ProductDetail_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_product_detail" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.CartActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_cart" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.ProductActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_product" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.UmallBaseActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_umall_base" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.ShopingChart"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_shoping_chart" >
       </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: repaste your xml file it's unclear

Comment: when i changes Splash activity name Aplication name also changes that is not Logical..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the application name in your string.xml file and then replace this line :

```
   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
   android:label="@string/appname"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Where "appname" is a string in string.xml like :

```
  <string name="appname">Umall</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

can have a label attribute. If it's absent the label is inherited from the parent component (either Activity or Application). So using this, you can set a label for the launcher icon, while still having the Activity with it's own title.

so change this

```
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.SplashActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

to this

```
       <activity
           android:name=".activity.SplashActivity_"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
           <intent-filter android:label="Umall">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

> better to use @string/app_name

more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)